# Linear space and Coordinates of vector

Tags: linear-algebra

Im taking a course on stepik.org on Linear Algebra. I come accross a problem...Please help....i mean how to initiate....

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Do you know what is a linear map? Do you know what is the matrix associated to a linear map?

Comment: yup linear maps are functions here any polynomial from p2 is mapped to p3 by the rule qp. Actually first thing im not getting is that how to evaluate p(-1)? is it that we take p(t) = a*t^2+b*t+c??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For linearity you have to consider to polynomials $p_1,p_2$ and $\lambda\in\mathbb K$ and prove
$$
\varphi(p_1+p_2)=\varphi(p_1)+\varphi(p_2)\text{ and }\varphi(\lambda p_1)=\lambda\varphi(p_1)
$$
Since you have to compare polynomials, you have to do it pointwise. So for an arbitrary $t$ you have to prove
$$
\varphi(p_1+p_2)(t)=\varphi(p_1)(t)+\varphi(p_2)(t)\text{ and }\varphi(\lambda p_1)(t)=\lambda\varphi(p_1)(t)
$$
Using the given notation, this is the same as
$$
q_{p_1+p_2}(t)=q_{p_1}(t)+q_{p_2}(t)\text{ and }q_{\lambda p_1}(t)=\lambda q_{p_1}(t).
$$
To find the matrix, you have to compute $\varphi(1)$, $\varphi(t)$ and $\varphi(t^2)$ and write it as a linear combination of the base $\{1,t,t^2,t^3\}$. The coefficients forms the matrix. More precisely:
If $$
\varphi(1)=a_{11}1+a_{21}t+a_{31}t^2+a_{41}t^3\\
\varphi(t)=a_{12}1+a_{22}t+a_{32}t^2+a_{42}t^3\\
\varphi(t^2)=a_{13}1+a_{23}t+a_{33}t^2+a_{43}t^3\\
$$
then the matrix is $$
A=\begin{pmatrix}a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\
a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} \\
a_{41} & a_{42} & a_{43}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: Here in p(-1) how to evalute it? is it like this? p(t) = a*t^2+b*t+c? then a,b &c are unknown...please help...im kinda confused..

Comment: Where do you want to evaluate it? For the linearity of $\varphi$, you don't need to.